# Create single VRT from images with the same name

Tags: python, gdal, vrt

I have a list of rasters some with the same date that I have to turn into VRTs with the same date too. The problem is that when I create a loop in the Gdal list it overwrites the VRTs that have the same name. While I want it to add them in the same VRT. E.g:

```
root = 'F:...\\MSAVI'
out_vrt = 'F:...\\out_vrt\\'

raster = [os.path.join(root, file) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root) 
               for file in files if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == '.tif' ]
raster 
['.../33TVE6/S2_20190712_079_33TVE6_B.tif',
 '.../32TQQ3/S2_20190712_079_33TQQ3_B.tif',
  ...] 

dates = []
for file in raster:
    dates.append(file.split('\\')[6].split('_')[1])

dates
['20190817',
 '20190901',
 ...]


for day in dates:
    for file in raster:
        data_path = file.split('\\')[6].split('_')[1]
        name = 'S2x2A_' + day + '_MSAVI.vrt'
        tile = file.split('\\')[6].split('_')[3]
        
        if day in data_path:

            my_vrt = gdal.BuildVRT(out_vrt+ name, file)
            my_vrt = None
```

The output is a VRT with only one raster:

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="4001" rasterYSize="4001">
  <SRS dataAxisToSRSAxisMapping="1,2">PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",15],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","32633"]]</SRS>
  <GeoTransform>  4.3500000000000000e+05,  1.0000000000000000e+01,  0.0000000000000000e+00,  4.4983300000000000e+06,  0.0000000000000000e+00, -1.0000000000000000e+01</GeoTransform>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Int16" band="1">
    <NoDataValue>-32768</NoDataValue>
    <ColorInterp>Gray</ColorInterp>
    <ComplexSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">F:...\33TVE6\S2_20190712_079_33TVE6_B_MSAVI.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="4001" RasterYSize="4001" DataType="Int16" BlockXSize="4001" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="4001" ySize="4001" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="4001" ySize="4001" />
      <NODATA>-32768</NODATA>
    </ComplexSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>
</VRTDataset>
```

How can I add rasters with the same date to get a VRT with more rasters without overwriting the previous VRT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`BuildVRT`](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#BuildVRT) can take a list of files as it's 2nd (source) parameter so you need to find all the files that match your date (using a full path) and pass that list to the function.

So something like:

```
for day in dates:
  f = [file for file in rasters if rasters.contains(day)]
  my_vrt = gdal.BuildVRT(out_vrt+name, f)
```

Comment: It works, good. If I wanted to divide into 'f' the rasters that differ for the '33TVE6' or '32TQQ3' tile and get a list with only files from spindle 32 or spindle 33, how could I do it?